# I need some help getting my python script to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need some help getting my python script to work on both python2 and python3. 
In python3, when I run the script and get to the part where you select the ITAG, it says:

```
From the lists above, find the ITAG number of the format you want to convert the video to.
Type the ITAG number here: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MrMcTiller/autopytubev2_working.py", line 299, in <module>
    Type the ITAG number here: """))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
>>>
```

[Here is a link to my python script.](https://github.com/MrMcTiller/AutoPyTube-Script/releases)

Comment: This question is much too vague. To improve it you need to ask specific questions.

Comment: @JackAidley, I updated the question.

Comment: When creating a title, try and describe the problem you have, not the fact that you have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have voted for re-open since you have a specific problem, but the question could be improved by bringing the specific section of code producing the problem into the question, and preferably creating a minimal complete example showing the problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help).

Comment: In short: We need your code, here. (Not all of it, in an external link. That is what [mcve] refers to.)

Comment: As others have said, we need your code... without that, it looks like you're calling `input` or `raw_input` (you've tagged this question with conflicting Python versions) and wrapping it in some other operation. The return value of `input` will be a string, regardless of what the user types; if you need an int or float (or any type other than string), you'll need to cast the input value before you can use it that way.

Comment: In addition to your code, this line is taking user input, and we really need that input to know how your code will respond.

Answer (score -1):

You appear to be trying to convert the empty string to a float. In Python3 `float('')` produces the error you describe, and will occur if the user responds to the input prompt by simply pressing return.